# JSON2HTML - Is there a command line option available to convert JSON to HTML?

Tags: json2html

Is there a command line option available to convert JSON to HTML?
I wanted a command line option like

```
json2html jsonstring transform > output.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sorry there isn't .. though you should be able to achieve something like this by writing a simple wrapper in node.js using the node module for json2html found here

https://github.com/moappi/node-json2html